# LibGDX OpenGL issue

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I have next two shaders:
vertex shader:

```
/// fragment shader
#version 130

in vec2 vs_uv;

out vec4 fs_color;

uniform sampler2D u_source;
uniform sampler2D u_map;

void main() {
    fs_color = vec4(vs_uv, 0, 1);
}

/// vertex shader
#version 130

out vec2 vs_uv;

void main() {
    const vec4 vertices[4] = {
        vec4(-1, -1, 0, 1),
        vec4(-1, 1, 0, 0),
        vec4(1, 1, 1, 0),
        vec4(1, -1, 1, 1)
    };

    vec4 description = vertices[gl_VertexID];
    gl_Position = vec4(description.xy, 0, 1);
    vs_uv = description.zw;
}
```

Obviously, it renders a full-screen gradient-filled rectangle.
I created a program with this two shaders and rendered 4 vertices into framebuffer and return rendered color texture from it:

```
public Texture apply(Texture source, Texture map) {
    m_renderBuffer.begin();
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(Gdx.gl20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    m_program.begin();
    m_program.setUniformi(m_sourceLocation, 0);
    m_program.setUniformi(m_mapLocation, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glDrawArrays(Gdx.gl20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    m_program.end();
    m_renderBuffer.end();

    return m_renderBuffer.getColorBufferTexture();
}
```

I draw rendered texture with a SpriteBatch:

```
m_lightSpriteBatch.begin();
m_lightSpriteBatch.draw(lightTexture, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
m_lightSpriteBatch.end();
```

It works well and renders gradient-filled rectangle as I want. When I bind two textures (passed as parameters for `apply` method - `source` and `map`) after meginning of the program:

```
m_program.begin();
source.bind(0);
map.bind(1);
...
```

It renders crap even considering what I use no textures in the shader's code! 
[image: preview]

1. texture rendered with no texture bindings
2. `source` texture
3. "crappy" rendered texture
4. `map` texture

Comment: How can there be parts in (3) that are not in (2)? For example "TNT" or "die" never occurs in any of the input textures you show. Are you having additional textures that contain this data?

Comment: It's one of textures I previously loaded before calling `apply`. It provides sprites for 2nd image. It's not a bunch of textures, it's one texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGL spec states that rendering the attached texture of a frame buffer onto its own frame buffer produces undefined results. Or "crap", in your words. :) I guess this shows that at least on this particular GPU, you can't even bind the texture, much less sample from it.

Typically, if you need do something like this, you need two FrameBuffers, and you can ping pong between them.

Comment: I created 2 framebuffers. First of them - for rendering scene and second - for rendering lights. Then I get two color textures from that buffers and use the `apply` function to pass them into third framebuffer. The interesting thing in `apply` method next. When I bind one of textures to 0 (i.e. GL_TEXTURE0), it renders same result as when I bind no textures. But when I bind one of textures to non-zero texture unit (i.e. GL_TEXTURE1 and other) it renders "crappy" texture.

Comment: @RealFresh SpriteBatch assumes the active texture unit is 0. So if you've been binding textures to other units, you need to make sure you call `Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0)` to reset it back to 0 before `batch.begin()`.

Comment: thanks, now it works well. I never thought what SpriteBatch not sets glActiveTexture by default.